# Как установить значение Map через JSF

Tags: map, jsf, xhtml

Подскажите, как заполнить значение в Map?
Есть такой код, но выдает ошибку: *value="#{entry.value}}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation*

```
<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{ProcessInfo.searchProperties}">
 <ui:repeat var="entry" value="#{item.entrySet().toArray()}">
    <p:outputLabel for="SearchForm" value="#{entry.key}:"/>
    <p:inputText id="SearchForm" value="#{entry.value}" />
 </ui:repeat> 
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно перенести значения `Map` в свой класс и работать на странице через него. Создаём DTO, в котором будут значения из `Map`:

```
public class EntryWrapper {

  private String key;
  private String value;

  public EntryWrapper(String key, String value) {
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
  }

  public String getKey() {
      return key;
  }

  public void setKey(String key) {
      this.key = key;
  }

  public String getValue() {
      return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
      this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Тестовый метод, возвращающий список для `JSF`-страницы:

```
ArrayList<EntryWrapper> result;
public List<EntryWrapper> getSearchProperties() {
    if (result == null) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("property1", "value1");
        map.put("property2", "value2");
        map.put("property3", "value3");
        map.put("property4", "value4");

        result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            result.add(new EntryWrapper(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Тестовый код `JSF`-страницы:

```
    <h:form>
        <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{staisticsController.searchProperties}">
            <p:outputLabel for="SearchForm" value="#{item.key}:"/>
            <p:inputText id="SearchForm" value="#{item.value}"/><br/>
        </ui:repeat>
        <h:commandButton value="SUBMIT"/>
    </h:form>
```

В связи с тем, что из приведённого в вопросе кода не до конца понятны типы итерируемых объектов, может потребоваться адаптация примера под Ваши нужды.